# When does equality hold in a specific triangle inequality?

Tags: reference-request, inequalities

I'd like to know when the equality holds in the following inequality
$$
| x - y |^a \le | x - z |^a + | y - z |^a.
$$

More precisely, for which points $x = (x_1, x_2)$, $y = (y_1, y_2)$ and $z = (z_1, z_2)$ in the plane does hold
$$
| x - y |^a = | x - z |^a + | y - z |^a
$$
where $a \in (0,1)$?

Notice that when $a=1, z$ can be any point in the line segment joining $x$ to $y$. That is, $z=tx+(1-t)y$ with $t \in (0,1)$. My conjecture is that for $a \in (0,1)$, $z$ must be in curve like cusp instead of a line joining $x$ and $y$.

In other words, is possible to find out a expression like $z=tx+(1−t)y$
as in the case $a=1$?

I tried the particular case: graph $1=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}+((x-1)^2+y^2)^{1/2}$. This is the case $x=(0,0)$, $y=(1,0)$ and $a=1/2$. I tried in geogebra and wolfram alpha, however I can not see any graph. I do not have softwares like mathematica. Can you help me.

Any help is good. Reference, direct proof, a picture or a link.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For $a\in(0,1)$ and any real $u,v\ge0$,
$$(u+v)^a\le u^a+v^a, \tag{1}\label{1}$$
with the equality if and only if $u=0$ or $v=0$.

Now,
$$|x-y|^a=|(x-z)+(z-y)|^a\le(|x-z|+|z-y|)^a \\ 
\le|x-z|^a+|z-y|^a
=|x-z|^a+|y-z|^a.$$
So, if $|x-y|^a=|x-z|^a+|y-z|^a$, then $(|x-z|+|z-y|)^a  
=|x-z|^a+|z-y|^a$, so that we have the equality in \eqref{1} with $u=|x-z|$ and $v=|z-y|$, which implies $u=0$ or $v=0$, that is, $x=z$ or $y=z$.

Vice versa, if $x=z$ or $y=z$, then clearly $|x-y|^a=|x-z|^a+|y-z|^a$.

We conclude that
$|x-y|^a=|x-z|^a+|y-z|^a$
if only if $x=z$ or $y=z$.

Comment: Sorry. Your first affirmation, but i already saw